# InDesign Script: export to IDML

Tags: javascript, scripting, export, adobe-indesign

I am trying to write a script to perform a data merge, followed by a find/replace, page add, and finally export. I can get it to perform the merge and find/replaces that are needed. When I add a new page manually I normally select the first page in the pages window then click add a new page at the bottom. Doing that makes every page after that go to 2 pages. I don't know how to do this in the script, what I tried below didn't work. It adds a new page at the end of the document.

```
app.activeDocument.pages.item(0).select();
app.activeDocument.pages.add();
```

After the merge, editing gets really slow, taking 15-20 per letter I add or delete.The only way i've found to have it edit like you'd expect is by exporting it to the IDML format then reopening that file in InDesign. I haven't been able to find much on exporting via a script in javascript. What I plan to try next is: `app.activeDocument.exportFile(ExportFormat.INDESIGN_MARKUP, newDoc, false);` But I don't know if that will work or not. I'm very new to scripting in InDesign. I'm using InDesign CS5.5 and here is the whole script thus far:

```
main();

function main()
{
    //Possibly let the user go find and choose a file
    //var mergeTemplate = File.openDialog();
    //var myDocument = app.open(mergeTemplate);

    //Open the template file to be used by the data merge.
    var myDocument = app.open(File("Macintosh HD/Users/Christian/Desktop/InDesign_Data_Merge/MMM14 Template_v1.indd"));
    //Load the data source
    var myDataSource = File("Macintosh HD/Users/Christian/Desktop/InDesign_Data_Merge/MMM v1.mer");

    myDocument.dataMergeProperties.selectDataSource(myDataSource);
    myDocument.dataMergeProperties.mergeRecords();

    //Save the document under a new name for later use.
    app.activeDocument.save(File("Macintosh HD/Users/Christian/Desktop/InDesign_Data_Merge/DataMerge_MMM.indd"));

    //Close the document, NOT saving original template,  so the original file is not destroyed or overwritten.
    myDocument.close(SaveOptions.no);

    //Find line break placeholder and replace with line break
    findReplace ("$$", "^n");
    //Find the tab placeholder and replace with tab
    findReplace ("##", "^t");

    //Select the first page of the document
    //app.activeDocument.pages.item(0).select();
    //Add another page to make the document print on both sides, like an open book
    //app.activeDocument.pages.add(); 

//export to IDML
//exportIDML();
}


function findReplace(findVal,replaceVal)
{
     // Clear the find/change text preferences.
    app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;

     // Set the find options
    app.findChangeTextOptions.caseSensitive = false;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.includeFootnotes = false;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.includeHiddenLayers = false;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.includeLockedLayersForFind = false;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.includeLockedStoriesForFind = false;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.includeMasterPages = false;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.wholeWord = false;

    // Search the document for the string findVal
    app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = findVal;
    // Change it to the string replaceVal
    app.changeTextPreferences.changeTo = replaceVal;
    // Perform the search-and-replace operation
    app.activeDocument.changeText();

}

function exportIDML()
{
    var newDoc = app.open(File("Macintosh HD/Users/Christian/Desktop/InDesign_Data_Merge/DataMerge_MMM.indd"));
    app.activeDocument.exportFile(ExportFormat.INDESIGN_MARKUP, newDoc, false);
}
```

**Edit:**
Another post led me to this site [jongware.mit.edu](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5js_html_3.0.3i/idcs5js/) but i'm not sure how to start searching for what I need here?

Comment: A minor note on your "template" `MMM14 Template_v1.indd`: if you save it as "Template" (under Format in the Save As dialog), or simply change its extension to `indt`, you will find ID opens a *copy* by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adding pages and flowing text

Instead of

```
app.activeDocument.pages.add();
```

you can use a handy parameter in the [`Pages.add`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5js_html_3.0.3i/idcs5js/pc_Pages.html#add) function:

```
app.activeDocument.pages.add(LocationOptions.AT_END);
```

You don't need the second parameter "reference", because `AT_END` already tells ID precisely where the new page must come (i.e., if you want to always add a page after the first one, you'd use `AFTER` for *at* and `app.activeDocument.pages[0]` for *reference*).

That, however, only **adds** a page. To make your text flow onto it, you need to manually add a new text frame and "thread" (link) the one from the previous page:

```
newframe = newpage.textFrames.add(..)
startframe.nextTextFrame = newframe; // <- thread
```

Unfortunately, only *adding* a new text frame to a page does not automatically size it to its parent page's margins. All you get is a tiny new frame in the top left. So you have to read out the page size (using its [`bounds`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Page.html#bounds) property) and the current [`margins`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_MarginPreference.html), and then you can resize the frame. Another snag awaits you, if your margins are *mirrored*: for some reason, the MarginPreferences object does not "see" whether you are on a left or a right hand sided page. So I use `page.index` to check if it's odd, and if so, reverse `left` and `right` margins.

Another possible pitfall is when your text contains Continuously Overset items -- text that will not fit on a page, whatever you do. That may happen with a large table, a large image, or text with some weird attribute such as a huge left indent or No-Break applied to more text than can fit on a single line. If not checked, this script would keep on checking for overflow, detect it, create a new page and text frame, which then will *also* overflow and so on and so forth. A quick check is to add a new text frame and check if it actually *contains* anything -- a Continuously Overflowing frame will always be entirely empty.

With that out of the way, here is the part that you can use instead of your own commented-out code. It assumes the to be added text is in an overset text frame on the very last page (index `-1`) of your current document. It also assumes this text frame is the only one on that page(!).

```
startframe = app.activeDocument.pages[-1].textFrames[0];
while (startframe.overflows)
{
    newpg = app.activeDocument.pages.add(LocationOptions.AT_END);
    newframe = newpg.textFrames.add();
    if (newpg.index & 1)
        newframe.geometricBounds = [newpg.bounds[0]+newpg.marginPreferences.top,
            newpg.bounds[1]+newpg.marginPreferences.left,
            newpg.bounds[2]-newpg.marginPreferences.bottom,
            newpg.bounds[3]-newpg.marginPreferences.right];
    else
        newframe.geometricBounds = [newpg.bounds[0]+newpg.marginPreferences.top,
            newpg.bounds[1]+newpg.marginPreferences.right,
            newpg.bounds[2]-newpg.marginPreferences.bottom,
            newpg.bounds[3]-newpg.marginPreferences.left];
    startframe.nextTextFrame = newframe;
    startframe = newframe;
//  Check for Continuous Overflow!
    if (startframe.contents.length == 0)
    {
        alert ("Continuous Overflow detected, cannot continue");
        break;
    }
}
```

---

### Exporting

That is an annoying issue you got, with ID slowing down after a Data Merge. I can't recall if that has been reported before; you might want to ask on the [Adobe InDesign forum](http://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign?view=discussions). Only *maybe*: perhaps you can manually try this. Directly after doing your merge, don't use "Save" but do a "Save As", and overwrite your old file. "Save As" cleans up and reallocates memory; I've found it sometimes helps. If that doesn't work, I cannot recommend anything else than, indeed, export to IDML and re-open that.

Your attempt to exporting to IDML is a fair one, but it contains a few mistakes!

First off, you should not use `app.open` -- this does what it says, it *opens* a previously saved file. You want to create a *new* file here; the parameter *to* in [`exportFile`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Document.html#exportFile) refers to the file that it will *create*. With your code, it would overwrite an existing file -- unless ID notices you already have it open and so complains about that. Not a statement I would be willing to test for correctness.

Second, you need to set its file extension correctly to `.idml` :)

A third, minor, point: the [`Folder`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Folder.html) object provides a handy shortcut to your Desktop folder.

```
var newDoc = new File(Folder.desktop+"/DataMerge_MMM.idml");
app.activeDocument.exportFile(ExportFormat.INDESIGN_MARKUP, newDoc);
```

---

#### Disclaimer

I don't have a CS5 at hand, I tested with my CS6. If you get errors on "unknown properties" and their ilk, call back in the morning and I will see what I can do.

Comment: Based on what you said I added the additional page using `app.activeDocument.pages.add(LocationOptions.AFTER,app.activeDocument.pages[0]);` and it gave the desired result. The information and tips on exporting worked as well! I understand what your code is doing, but I don't understand why you're suggesting it? When the data is merged, it creates a new page for each record. There is some overset text, but I run TextStitch to make the document flow like a book and it fixes that. Haven't figured out how to run that from the script, though it's not as important.

Comment: @Jonathan: the idea something was going wrong with new pages during Data Merge must have gotten stuck in my mind. But, glad you could solve it based on my hints! To chain another script after yours is finished, you could try [app.doScript](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcsjs5.5/pc_Application.html#doScript).